Why are Chrome devTools trying to load source maps from a wrong folder?
In devtools of a React app on prod I see that it tries to load source files from a wrong location:
https://localhost/appcontent/js/js/app.js.map?771acda80c2a2a0f
Source maps were created and are in fact in a different folder (verified by applying them manually):
https://localhost/appcontent/source-map/js/app.js.map?771acda80c2a2a0f
Why are devTools looking for a wrong folder?
webpack.config.js
...
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'this',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js?[contenthash]',
    publicPath: '/appcontent/',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?[contenthash]',
    pathinfo: !isProduction,
    hashFunction: 'xxhash64'
  },
...
 optimization: {
    minimize: isProduction,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserJSPlugin({
        parallel: true,
        minify: TerserJSPlugin.swcMinify,
        terserOptions: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      }),
      new CssMinimizerPlugin()
    ],
    sideEffects: isProduction
  },
...
isProduction &&
      new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: './source-map/[file].map[query]',
        moduleFilenameTemplate: '[resource-path]',
        append: '\n//# sourceMappingURL=[file].map[query]',
        exclude: /lib\..*.*/
      }),
...

Why are devTools looking for a wrong folder? How can I change that?
